# MongoDB explain shows {$in: ["bar"]} same as {$eq:"bar"} (E in ESR) so why does Atlas Suggested Index put foo at the end of compound index (R in ESR)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-indexes

We have a lot of queries that are checking that a field value is in a set, but 99.9% of the time that set is a singleton. I was under the impression that MongoDB was smart enough to recognize `{ $in: ["bar"]}` as the same as `{ $eq: "bar"}` and explain supports this, but MongoDB Atlas Performance Advisor Suggested Indexes seems to think of these as sets and therefor R in ESR index order. Is this just a limitation of Atlas?

Here is an example where `parent` is a singleton set, but is suggested after the sort `created_utc`
[image: Example Atlas Suggested Index]

PS the purpose of this question is to convince my team to convert to `$eq` vs `$in` in this case so that we can better utilize Atlas (or for Atlas team to see this and fix it lol)

Comment: Use the explain command to see how it processes the query.  Even with multiple values in the $in expression, it should be able to use a sort_merge instead of a full in-memory sort.

Comment: @Joe yes, that's why I think they are equivalent. I'm going to re-word the question to make it more specific about the Atlas issue

Comment: `{ $in: ["bar"]}` is directly equivalent to `{ $or: [{field:"bar"}]}`, since the database has no idea was ESR even is, it won't be considering which of those it might be.

Comment: @Joe the database doesn't, but MongoDB Atlas Performance Advisor Suggested Indexes certainly does

Comment: Have you tested that index using explain?  I suspect it performs just as well as placing `parent` before `created_utc`, but also supports the query variations where the array has more than one entry.

Comment: When I have time I'll test it on our dev environment, but that would imply ESR doesn't matter